# user specific objects within Google Cloud Storage buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want each user to have their own specific folder inside my Google Cloud Storage account so everyone only has access to their own object. However I am a little confused on how to give different access to users as such. (Each user needs read, write and delete access to their objects.)

I thought Firebase storage security rules would be perfect but I can't really use them since this is a desktop application. ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394230/firebase-storage-not-working-in-express-server-environment/37396389#37396389))

I've also tried using IAM roles but that didn't really help in per user basis access.

Uploading the files through my server was another idea I had in mind which turned out the be incredibly inefficient.

Currently setting up Cloud Storage Access Control Lists to grant access to users dynamically but I was just wondering if this is the best way to handle the problem.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage is not designed to provide the granularity of permissions to objects within a bucket. Note that folders (directories) do not exist in buckets, folders are emulated via the object's name. Probably a better solution is to use Google Drive.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that there is no actual folder structure but using cloud storage help the process so much since I just send the media straight to google speech to text from the bucket and can't really do that using the drive.

Comment: What about allowing the bucket to be written to by the set of all users.  When you upload an object, that object should then be owned by the user that uploaded it allowing them to read and delete it.  No other user would be allowed to access the object.  Would that not be sufficient?

Comment: That would be sufficient but I'm not sure how would I implement what you described,  how does client know which user uploaded the file later on?

Comment: I just tried a test.  I created an object in a bucket as user "X" and then examined the permissions on that object.  I find that the object has a "User" "Owner" of "X".  I then created a second object as user "Y" and that object has a "User" Owner" permission of "Y".  From this I am thinking that the user who creates the object becomes the "User/Owner" of the object which should be both honored and queryable.

Comment: Yeah I see but there is no authentication apart from firebase, how does gcloud storage know who is currently requesting the file. Since theese are just gcloud store bucket reads from users through a node js application.

Comment: Why not create a bucket for each user?

Comment: "Because there are limits to bucket creation and deletion, you should design your storage applications to favor intensive object operations and relatively few buckets operations." I wanted to keep the bucket operations low.